# Trigger to update another table error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create an update trigger in MySQL Community Server 5.5.16. I have two tables:

```
create table sales
    (ono integer primary key,
     dnr integer not null,
     osum integer);

create table salessum
    (dnr integer primary key,
     dsum integer);



alter table sales
    add constraint fk_sales_salessum foreign key (dnr) 
            references salessum (dnr);
```

I need to update table "salessum" after any update in table "sales". I have created trigger:

```
Create trigger up_to_date
after update on sales
for each row
begin
update salessum
set dsum = dsum + new.osum;
where dnr=new.dnr;
end;
```

But I've got an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where
 dnr=new.dnr' at line 1
```

Could anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `;` in your trigger and since the trigger contains semicolons, you need to change the delimiter temporarily to add the trigger;

```
delimiter //

Create trigger up_to_date
after update on sales
for each row
begin
update salessum
set dsum = dsum + new.osum
where dnr=new.dnr;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an errant `;` after the `SET` clause:

```
update salessum
set dsum = dsum + new.osum;  <--- Remove that
where dnr=new.dnr;
```

Whenever MySQL tells you to *check the manual for the right syntax to use near xxx*, look first to the character immediately preceding *xxx* to see if there is an error there. In this case, right before the `WHERE` clause began.

Answer (score 1):

You have one `;` too much in your syntax

```
Create trigger up_to_date
after update on sales
for each row
begin
    update salessum
    set dsum = dsum + new.osum  /*removed ; here */
    where dnr=new.dnr;
end;
```

And don't forget the delimiter around your trigger

Example:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEGIN
...
END;
//
delimiter;
```